# C++ Try to access protected member in base class (read access violation)

Tags: c++, qt

I try to to call a method but it crashes when it trys to access a QMap member variable of AbstractIpCalculator.

I am calling like this:

```
AbstractIpCalculator *calculator = item_group.at(i).getCalculator();

calculator->setId(1, net_ids[1]);
```

ABSTRACTIPCALCULATOR_H:

```
#ifndef ABSTRACTIPCALCULATOR_H
#define ABSTRACTIPCALCULATOR_H

#include <QString>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QPair>
#include <QQueue>



class AbstractIpCalculator
{

public:
    AbstractIpCalculator();

    ...

    bool setId(int index, double value);

    virtual QString calculate(QString) = 0;


protected:
    QMap<int, double> park_netz_list;
    ...    

private:
    virtual QString calculateOctetOne(QString) = 0;
    virtual QString calculateOctetTwo(QString) = 0;
    virtual QString calculateOctetThree(QString) = 0;
    virtual QString calculateOctetFour(QString) = 0;
};

#endif // ABSTRACTIPCALCULATOR_H
```

The method setParkNetzId:

```
bool AbstractIpCalculator::setId(int index, double value)
{
    if(index >= 1)
    {
        qDebug() << index << value << " " << (&park_netz_list == nullptr);
        park_netz_list.insert(index, value); // <--- crash!!!
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

There are many subclasses which extend AbstractIpCalculator. *calculator is a derived class but at this point I don't know which.

My debugger says : read access violation at: 0x0, flags=0x0 (first chance) and stops in qmap.h line 73.

I am using Qt 5.0.2.

Thank you in advance!

EDIT:

Is maybe something  wrong with the setCalculator or getCalculator method?

```
AbstractIpCalculator *CalculatorItemGroup::getCalculator() const
{
    return calculator_item;
}

void CalculatorItemGroup::setCalculator(AbstractIpCalculator &calculator_item)
{
    this->calculator_item = &calculator_item;
}
```

initialization:

```
CalculatorItemGroup item;
item..setCalculator(c);
```

Comment: Run your program under valgrind or similar to figure out where it is going wrong.  Or if you can't use valgrind, use a debugger, and figure out which derived class is involved, etc.  It could be simple memory corruption somewhere in code you haven't shown us.  And are you sure getCalculator() isn't returning null?

Comment: Do I need to cast the base class to a subclass? I only need to call methods from the base class. The method setId is in the base class and the variable park_netz_list, too.

Comment: That part is probably OK.  Also make sure you're compiling with warnings enabled.

Comment: are you sure that `calculator` of your first code fragment is a valid pointer? the rest of the code looks ok. if the pointer is invalid the calling of insert actually may be the first place there something from the this-object is dereferenced. so it may break here if the pointer was corrupted.

Comment: The pointer is valid. (calculator == nullptr) = false. I also get the qDebug() output ( 0x604f664 1 143   false ) in setId. But after the output it immediately crashes.

Comment: `calculator!=nullptr` does *not* imply that `calculator` is a valid pointer to a `AbstractIpCalculator` instance. It only proves that it isn't NULL.

Comment: Okay, you guys were right. The problem is that my object `c` in `item.setCalculator(c);` goes out of scope so it is no longer available.